# In C#, does the DataReceived event handler of the SerialPort class execute on it's own thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I have a C# program which communicates over a serial port, using the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class. In order to receive data, I am subscribing to its DataReceived event handler.

My question is, when data is received - does the DataReceived event run in its own thread, or does it remain synchronous? i.e. will the Send() function be blocked until DataReceived is complete? If I use thread locking mechanisms such as AutoResetEvent(s), by default will this block the UI thread?

Cheers guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSDN says:

> The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is
>   received from the SerialPort object. Because this event is raised on a
>   secondary thread, and not the main thread, attempting to modify some
>   elements in the main thread, such as UI elements, could raise a
>   threading exception. If it is necessary to modify elements in the main
>   Form or Control, post change requests back using Invoke, which will do
>   the work on the proper thread.

So yes.

[SerialPort.DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)